# Is there any better way to achieve Notion oAuth in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, oauth, firebase-dynamic-links, notion-api

Notion Auth API doesn't support scheme, it only supports https:// as redirect url

In my Flutter (Android) app I am using [Flutter Custom tabs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_tabs) and Firebase Dynamic Links for notion OAuth2 apis.

My dynamic link is https://myappname.page.link/start

The deep link is https://myappname.page.link

Notion is using the https://myappname.page.link/start as a redirect_url , and is supposed to append some parameters to it, so it looks like https://myappname.net?code=xxx

However, all I receive inside my app is the naked url https://myappname.page.link

There are no parameters attached to it.

After researching for more than 2 hours, I know I can't customise this using Firebase Dynamic Links.

Is there a better way to listen for incoming response inside of a Flutter app, without the use of Dynamic Links?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `state` param and pass there whatever you want. It's a part of the OAuth, so notion auth API should add the param to your redirect url.

https://developers.notion.com/docs/authorization